# Authentication via OAuth 2.0 with YouTube

Tags: api, oauth, youtube

I've been struggling for some time now, trying to figure out how to make a button that redirects to a page asking for permission and then sending the partial information of their accounts to my database or email address and  give other actions such as subscribing.

An example of who is doing this is `socialblade` and `fullscreen`, they're using it quite nicely and I would love to use this in the future.